# conditionally dropping rows from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to conditionally drop rows of from a pandas dataframe and running into trouble. For example, I want to drop the second and third rows from the dataframe in the example below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [12, 10, 7, 0],
    [11, 0, 0, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 6, 7, 5],
    [4, 11, 3,4],
    [5, 2, 5, 0]],
    columns=["num1", "num2","num3","num3"])
```

I've tried:

```
df.loc[~(df['num2','num3']==0).all(axis=1)]
```

but get the error "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

I've also tried this per a suggestion below and gotten unexpected output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ne` with `all` as:

```
df = df.loc[df[['num2','num3']].ne(0).all(axis=1)]
print(df)
   num1  num2  num3  num4
0    12    10     7     0
3     0     6     7     5
4     4    11     3     4
5     5     2     5     0
```

Here is the screenshot of my execution:

[image: Output]

Comment: It looks like that should work, but when I run that code, I get only the rows labeled 3 and 4. 

`        num1  num2  num3  num4
    3     0     6     7     5
    4     4    11     3     4`

Comment: @jmark7453 It is not possible, can you check it again?

Comment: Tried resetting everything and still got that output. (I can't seem to attach an image of the code input/output, but that's what I'm getting)

Comment: @jmark7453 You don't want rows that contains both `num2` and `num3` equal to 0. or you just want to filter row 1 and row 2. Also check the datatypes of the columns they should be int.

Comment: Yes. I want the output that you got and the datatypes are int. 

If it matters, I'm running python 3.7.6

Comment: I edited the original post to show a screenshot of my input/output using this method. I'm not sure why/how we are getting different outputs, since it looks like our inputs are exactly the same

Comment: @jmark7453 You forgot to change the name of last column. It should be `num4` check it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df.loc[(df['num2']!=0) & (df['num2']!=0)]
```

Comment: When I try that, I get the following error: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'